# loading an image, is the width/height pixel count maintained

Tags: android

I have read all about supporting different screens and I understand the concept of Density Pixels (DP). However one thing I am not sure about. Lets say I have an image file which is 200 by 200 pixels and I loaded it using xml with wrap_content attributes at the top left of the screen (0,0). Now let's say I want to place a textview programmatically beside it.

If I put the text view at coordinates (250,0). Does that mean that the text view will never overlap the image and will always be to the right no matter what the device density/screen size is.

I understand the distance ( gap) will be different but I am hoping my theory of not overlapping will hold.

I tried it on 2 device and no issues but I am not sure if this is coincendence

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using px unit it will always remain the same. But if you are using dp unit instead of pixel you cannot definitely be sure.

By the way you should use toRightOf property instead of this approach if you only want this.

Comment: Thank you, yea I am aware of that. But  I have to stay withing the framelayout and can't use relativelayout